# Decrypt string to number value

Tags: c#

> I have my code to decrypt the string to numbers but i have the result
>   every time "-1-1-1"

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decryptScore(txtscore.Text);
}



public string decryptScore(string s)
{
     string[] firstDigitArray = { "f85au", "kt50e", "cmt5s", "v5072", "fc5i3", "56f7l", "7gj81", "yn90y", "5o3ko", "ntakn" };
     string[] secondDigitArray = { "hkym6", "xj97c", "54v6q", "nawf9", "9e1gp", "9gww9", "5oj5p", "0ba5t", "yizld", "bt064" };
     string[] thirdDigitArray = { "uku91", "rn2k4", "uuq78", "nkurt", "8kxqs", "9p7kc", "hd8x6", "57b6o", "7iucu", "do6bq" };
     string[] fourthDigitArray = { "0hdro", "0wqrc", "wa5ny", "857mg", "3f7ro", "kerph", "0mhw1", "tpb8f", "8rho3", "4hc11" };

     string[][] digitsArray = {firstDigitArray, secondDigitArray, thirdDigitArray, fourthDigitArray};

     string decryptedScore = "";
     int scorelength = s.Length / 5;

     for (int i = 0; i < scorelength; i++)
     {
         string d = s.Substring(i * 5, 5);
         decryptedScore += (digitsArray[i][i].IndexOf(d));
     }
     score.Text = decryptedScore;
     return decryptedScore;
 }
```

Comment: What is the string `s` with which you call this function?

Comment: Do you have some sample input with expected output?

Comment: I hope you realize this isn't a secure encryption scheme. More an obfuscation, suitable for casual purposes only.

Comment: Without more explanation of what you put in, and what you expect to get out, we can't be of much help.

Comment: @Floris i edited my question y can see s

Comment: Side note: you should comment/vote on answers... And really should accept answer to your previous question you are using in this one.

Comment: You could do a check: if the index is `-1`, throw an exception that the score is invalid. You still won't succeed with the input you used here, but at least it'll be easier to see the exception than to know why you're getting `-1-1-1`.

Comment: `txtscore.Text` is still not the value of the string. You still haven't given enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: @nick yes i had sample as 327 = v507254v6q57b6o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string decryptScore(string s)
{
    var firstDigitArray = new List<string>{ "f85au", "kt50e", "cmt5s", "v5072", "fc5i3", "56f7l", "7gj81", "yn90y", "5o3ko", "ntakn" };
    var secondDigitArray = new List<string> { "hkym6", "xj97c", "54v6q", "nawf9", "9e1gp", "9gww9", "5oj5p", "0ba5t", "yizld", "bt064" };
    var thirdDigitArray = new List<string> { "uku91", "rn2k4", "uuq78", "nkurt", "8kxqs", "9p7kc", "hd8x6", "57b6o", "7iucu", "do6bq" };
    var fourthDigitArray = new List<string> { "0hdro", "0wqrc", "wa5ny", "857mg", "3f7ro", "kerph", "0mhw1", "tpb8f", "8rho3", "4hc11" };

    var digitsArray = new List<List<string>>{ firstDigitArray, secondDigitArray, thirdDigitArray, fourthDigitArray };

    string decryptedScore = "";
    int scorelength = s.Length / 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < scorelength; i++)
    {
        string d = s.Substring(i * 5, 5);
        decryptedScore += (digitsArray[i].FindIndex(x=>x==d));
    }

    return decryptedScore;

}
```

*PS: Don't forget if `scorelength` is greater or equal to 4 you'll get an exception(since you only have 4 `digitArrays`)*

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
decryptedScore += (digitsArray[i][i].IndexOf(d));
```

you are searching for a string a single string for a the value.  You need to search the array.

Change this line to

```
decryptedScore += Array.IndexOf(digitsArray[i], d);
```

This will search the array for a particular value and return you it's index.  As a result you will get the required number back.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`decryptedScore += (digitsArray[i][i].IndexOf(d));`

with

`decryptedScore += Array.IndexOf(digitsArray[i], d);`